# Merge RDF .ttl files into one file database - filtering and keeping only the data/triples needed

Tags: java, rdf, jena, ttl, rdf4j

I need to merge 1000+ .ttl files into one file database. How can I merge them with filtering the data in the source files and keep only the data needed in the target file?

Thanks

Comment: the phrase *"merge specific classes"* can't be answered given that an RDF dataset is a set of triples, so you first have to define which triples to keep in the merged dataset. And don't answer with "related" - that's also not a precise answer. You have to be as specific as possible, otherwise you can't create a procedure that does the filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of options, but the simplest way is probably to have use a Turtle parser to read all the files, and let that parser pass its output to a handler which does the filtering before in turn passing the data to a Turtle writer.

Something like this would probably work (using RDF4J):

```
  RDFWriter writer = org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, outFile);

  writer.startRDF();
  for (File file : // loop over your 100+ input files) {
      Model data = Rio.parse(new FileInputStream(file), "", RDFFormat.TURTLE);
      for (Statement st: data) {
         if (// you want to keep this statement) {
              writer.handleStatement(st);
         }
      }
  }
  writer.endRDF();
```

Alternatively, just load all the files into an RDF Repository, and use SPARQL queries to get the data out and save to an output file, or if you prefer: use SPARQL updates to *remove* the data you don't want before exporting the entire repository to a file.

Something along these lines (again using RDF4J):

```
 Repository rep = ... // your RDF repository, e.g. an in-memory store or native RDF database

 try (RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection()) {

    // load all files into the database
    for (File file: // loop over input files) {
        conn.add(file, "", RDFFormat.TURTLE);
    }

    // do a sparql update to remove all instances of ex:Foo
    conn.prepareUpdate("DELETE WHERE { ?s a ex:Foo; ?p ?o }").execute();

    // export to file
    con.export(Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, outFile));
 } finally {
    rep.shutDown(); 
 }
```

Depending on the amount of data / the size of your files, you may need to extend this basic setup a bit (for example by using transactions instead of just letting the connection auto-commit). But you get the general idea, hopefully.

Comment: I only just now noticed that this question was tagged with 'jena', apologies. I'm reasonably certain the above approaches can be done using Jena instead of RDF4J as well.

Comment: To be more specific with the problem: I need to merge all the files .ttl from this database   https://github.com/DOREMUS-ANR/knowledge-base/blob/master/data/philharmonie/pp.works.tar.gz   with keeping only the classes F22 and F28. So at the end I will have one file .ttl with the mentioned classes only - no other information: How can I do it? For me it is important the final result - through Jena or RDF4J does not matter much for me. I prefer the simplest variant.

Comment: @Aram I think that's probably doable using one of the approaches I mentioned above. You should edit your original question to clarify what specific problem you're facing and where you're stuck. Have a look at [ask], which gives useful tips on how to write a question that has a good chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: @Aram The question is, what means *"with keeping only the classes F22 and F28."* - RDF is made of triples, so it remains unclear which triples you want to have in the merged dataset ...

Comment: I need to create one file database with merging the data from different files, keeping only the data/triples I will need. Considering the database I mentioned I will need the following data / triples to merge in one file: efrbroo:F28_Expression_Creation
ecrm:P9_consists_of
ecrm:E7_Activity
ecrm:P14_carried_out_by
ecrm:E21_Person
ecrm:P131_is_identified_by
mus:U31_had_function
efrbroo:F11_Corporate_Body  . 
My problem is how to construct a query, which will merge all the .ttl files into one .ttl file with keeping only the mentioned data/triples.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies and sorry for lot of questions. I am new to RDF and I need to understand how to manipulate them

Comment: @Aram I suggest your best way forward is to give it a try using one of the approaches above. Then, if you get stuck, you can ask a new, more specific question about the precise bit you're struggling with.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thanks a lot for the help. I have opened a new question with code compilation problems here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207723/rdf4j-ttl-files-code-compilation-problems

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I am trying to run the repo  version but instead of writing the query result to the new file I get the full file content in the new file. I have made it with SELECT statement.  Here is the query I am running:

Comment: conn.prepareQuery("PREFIX ecrm:<http://erlangen-crm.org/current/>  \n"
     + "PREFIX foaf: <" + FOAF.NAMESPACE + "> \n"
     + "PREFIX mus: <http://data.doremus.org/ontology#>  \n"
     + "SELECT ?artist ?name "
     + "WHERE { "
     + "?func mus:U31_had_function []; "
     + "ecrm:P14_carried_out_by ?artist . "
     + "?artist foaf:name ?name"
     + " }");
      
   conn.export(Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, outFile));
   }

Comment: How can I get the result of my SELECT query with repo version? Thanks

Comment: 'try (RepositoryConnection conn = db.getConnection()) {
 File dir = new File("ttl/");
 String[] fileNames = dir.list();
 for (String file : fileNames) {
        File f = new File(dir, file);
        conn.add(f, "", RDFFormat.TURTLE);
        String queryString = "...";
 TupleQuery query = conn.prepareTupleQuery(queryString);
  try (TupleQueryResult result = query.evaluate()) {
   while (result.hasNext()){
   BindingSet solution = result.next();
    SOP("?artist =" + solution.getValue("artist"));
    SOP("?name = " + solution.getValue("name"));} }finally{
db.shutDown();}  '

Comment: @Aram I suggest that you look at the rdf4j tutorials and the javadoc and try to understand how the code works. Go over it line by line. Hint: your use of the `export` method in combination with a query here is incorrect.